# Does fileprivate Extensions and Types in Swift improve compile time?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, compile-time

If I keep my extension and private Types very confined inside one single Swift file because I will only ever need it inside that one file, will it improve compiler time and/or performance? Or is the Swift compiler so intelligent and doesn't matter at all?

Example:
One iOS Xcode project with over 600 Swift files (moderately huge project) with an already existing network class:

NetworkController.swift

```
class NetworkController {
    let queue = OperationQueue()

    func add(_ op: Operation) {
        queue.addOperation(op)
    }
}
```

Now I need to add a new class which only does a legacy operation. Which means that all the other components in the iOS app will never ever need it.

LegacyController.swift (everything put into same file)

```
internal final class LegacyController {
    let network = NetworkController()

    func start() {
        network.requestSomeLegacyStuff {
            print("blub")
        }
        // do lots of other work here ...
    }
}

extension NetworkController {
    fileprivate func requestSomeLegacyStuff(success: () -> Void) {
        let operation = RequestLegacyDataOperation()

        add(operation)
    }
}

fileprivate final class RequestLegacyDataOperation: Operation {
    // do lots of work here ...
}
```

**VERSUS** put them into their own files for better visibility and separation, but would then need to change to `internal` scope, which is not needed at all.

LegacyController.swift

```
internal final class LegacyController {
    let network = NetworkController()

    func start() {
        network.requestSomeLegacyStuff {
            print("blub")
        }
        // do lots of other work here ...
    }
}
```

NetworkController+LegacyStuff.swift

```
extension NetworkController {
    internal func requestSomeLegacyStuff(success: () -> Void) {
        let operation = RequestLegacyDataOperation()

        add(operation)
    }
}
```

RequestLegacyDataOperation.swift

```
internal final class RequestLegacyDataOperation: Operation {
    // do lots of work here ...
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? What are your experiences?